# Cannot map sub-domain to node server running on amazon ec2

Tags: node.js, apache, amazon-ec2

I am running one node application on port 7777 on an ec2 Instance.
I can access that application with ec2 instance's IP address like this -

`52.77.122.38:7777` (Not the real IP address)

Now I created one `A` entry in `route53` for abc.mydomain.com and put IP address of my ec2 instance there,
Now loading `abc.mydomain.com` gives me apache server homepage.

To open this node app on this subdomain,

I removed all the virtualhost entries in `apache2.conf` file and added this -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  abc.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.abc.mydomain.com

    ProxyRequests on

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:7777/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:7777/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

but loading abc.mydomain.com gives me 'this site can't be reached'. While I can still access my app at `<ec2's Ip address>:7777`

How do I get it running on abc.mydomain.com?

Comment: `http://abc.mydomain.com` is accessing your website using port 80. Have you tried `http://abc.mydomain.com:7777`? Edit: I can see you're trying to reverse proxy port 80 to 7777, but I just wanted to make sure the domain is pointing where it should.

Comment: yes http://abc.mydomain.com:7777 is working, why so?

Comment: You didn't mention trying the domain, so I just wanted to make sure as that was the first thing I'd check. Anyways, I don't know Apache very well but did you enable `mod_proxy`?

Comment: Try to look at security groups settings for EC2 instance. Port 80 must be opened for inbound traffic. Like you did with :7777 if it's working

Comment: @Randy I checked it only after you told me. How do I enable `mod_proxy`?